# Why is there a restriction for females in NASA?

Tags: plot-explanation, hidden-figures

In Hidden Figures, There is a scene where Paul Stafford stops Katherine Johnson from entering into the meeting.

> Paul Stafford: There is no protocol for women attending.
>
> Katherine Johnson: There's no protocol for a man circling the Earth
>   either, sir.

[image]

Later, she is allowed by Alan into the meeting.

There is another scene where we can see control room filled with only men:

[image]

Later Alan welcomes Katherine into the Friendship 7 Control Room.

Why is there is a restriction for women in NASA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is there is a restriction for women in NASA?

### It wasn't just NASA

**It was the culture of the time in the US**.

In the late 1950's and early 1960's women weren't treated as equals in the workplace (I won't get into how that has progressed since as it's a much wider subject).

Professional roles such as scientists and mathematicians were almost exclusively male *and white* in 1960's America.

The fact was that in 1962 most "professional" positions for women would have been secretarial or the like. The most a woman could expect in the way of supervisory or managerial positions would have been in charge of **other women**. Mrs Mitchell in *Hidden Figures* is a prime example right in this movie.

Rising to positions of authority or roles outside of the norm would have been most unusual...**at the time**...unless the woman was exceptionally talented *and* given the opportunity....and a level playing field.

Comment: +1. I grew up in that period.  The jobs in the classified section of the newspaper were all neatly organized: help wanted male, help wanted male (colored), help wanted female, and help wanted female (colored). Guess which section all the engineering job were in?